# How to do Object Tracking with the help of Unity Engine?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, arkit, arcore

Need to do an object tracking based app.What I will have is either an FBX model or CAD drawing.I have tested Object Tracking using ARkit2.0 , in that using UnityARObjectAnchor scene.In that scene we need to convert the object into ARkit recognizable that is .arobject by scanning the it.

We cannot convert CAD/FBX into .arobject because from what I read .arobject contains only feature points to make it recognizable again.Vuforia supports CAD drawing but their pricing will be heavy.Any idea how we can use FBX/CAD information for Object tracking/Detection?Should I use 3rd party apps?Really looking forward to do an Object Tracking based AR app.

Comment: I hardly think you can find a free/cheap 3rd party software that can track objects. Therefore, either you will implement this or pay for it. If you have only one object i think you can  but if you want something more robust than you need to pay for it.

Comment: @AliKanat any idea which all SDK which can be used with Unity to achieve my purpose

Comment: Well you can use [Visionlib SDK](https://visionlib.com/) but it is not free and i do not know how much it is.

Comment: I have tested visionlib they provide only three tests in device which was over...

Comment: Well as i said object tracking requires sophisticated algorithms and i do not think you can find a free SDK that does it for you.